# How to combine same-functionality methods into one

Tags: c#

I have 2 namespaces which are used in a same C# source code file. The 2 namespaces are got from third party SOAP web services
and they contains same name proxy classes such as Person and Address.  Those classes have the same structure and **I cannot modify
because they are automatically code-generated by Visual Studio**.

namespaceA.Person
namespaceA.Address

namespaceB.Person
namespaceB.Address

Details of proxy classes that are automatically code-generated by Visual Studio:

```
public class Person{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    // complex type property
    public Address Adress {get;set;}
}

public class Address{
    public string StreetLine1 {get;set;}
    public string StreetLine2 {get;set;}

    public string City {get;set;}
    public string Province {get;set;}
    public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

I write 2 methods which have different names but they do the same functions, and I must use full namespace identificators to avoid namespaces conflicts in a same C# code file. 
I would like to combine those 2 methods into 1 and to get rid of source codes duplicates. Thanks for your help.

The 2 methods which do the same functionality:

```
public namespaceA.Person SetPersonForNameSpaceA(string fn, string ln, string sl1, string sl2, string city, string prv, string cc)
{
    var p = new namespaceA.Person
    {
        FirstName = fn,
        LastName = ln,

        Address = new namespaceA.Address
        {
            StreetLine1 = sl1,
            StreetLine2 = sl2,
            City = city
            Province = prv,
            CountryCode = cc
        }
    };

    return p;
}

public namespaceB.Person SetPersonForNameSpaceB(string fn, string ln, string sl1, string sl2, string city, string prv, string cc)
{
    var p = new namespaceB.Person
    {
        FirstName = fn,
        LastName = ln,

        Address = new namespaceB.Address
        {
            StreetLine1 = sl1,
            StreetLine2 = sl2,
            City = city
            Province = prv,
            CountryCode = cc
        }
    };

    return p;
}
```

I would like to have just only 1 method and that method must be bound correctly to a concrete class of a namespace that is based on consumer's context usage option.  The question marks (?) are my code questions.  I tried to use generic type T but I failed because the T's properties cause compile error at coding time in VS.

```
public ? SetPerson(string fn, string ln, string sl1, string sl2, string city, string prv, string cc)
{
    var p = new ?
    {
        FirstName = fn,
        LastName = ln,

        Address = new ?
        {
            StreetLine1 = sl1,
            StreetLine2 = sl2,
            City = city
            Province = prv,
            CountryCode = cc
        }
    };

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Try to add an `using (namespacenamehere)` and then call the method

Comment: Reflection is a possible solution here. You could pass a type of person as a parameter.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for compile time checking, but if you're not then use serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Does you really have 2 third parties that define a `Person` class and an `Address` class exactly the same way? This look suspicious! If in reality definitions come from the same source, then maybe it should be a single namespace to start with... Otherwise, with reflection, you can copy objects so you won't need duplicate code.

Comment: Only sane solution is to get the generated classes to be partial, and to add a common interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Usually auto-generated classes are `partial`. See if you can tweak your generator for this. In this case you can introduce a common interface. See [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).
2. If (1) is not an option, just use `dynamic` keyword.

   ```
   public TPerson SetPerson<TPerson, TAddress>(string fn, string ln, string sl1, string sl2, string city, string prv, string cc) where TPerson : new() where TAddress : new()
   {
       var p = new TPerson();
       dynamic dp = p;

       dp.FirstName = fn;
       dp.LastName = fn;

       dynamic addr = new TAddress();
       dp.Address = addr;  
       addr.City = city;

       // ...

       return  p;
   }
   ```

   Then call like this:

   ```
   SetPerson<namespaceA.Person, namespaceA.Address>("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
   SetPerson<namespaceB.Person, namespaceB.Address>("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
   ```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I follow yours and the codes are working.  By the way. if I used a common interface and partial classes, how can I proceed?